# Stop instgrm.Embeds.process() from running on load Instagram embed.js

Tags: instagram, embed

I am trying to disable Instagrams embed.js from running process once that script loads, but can't seem to figure out how to do that. I am loading the script myself (aka not included in instagrams response) and don't want it to process/parse the html when the script loads

I manually trigger instgrm.Embeds.process on the specific el when the load is needed and this onload functionality that instagram comes with is causing double loading issues and negating my lazy loading.

Anyone know how to stop this? Anyone from the instagram team provide any feedback?

Answer (score 0):

https://www.instagram.com/developer/embedding/#oembed

Try adding the 'omitscript=true' param to the API call. Does that work?